# Database requirement for fast for sharepoint 2010?

Tags: fast-search, database, administration, crawling

We would like to install Fast for Sharepoint 2010 in our medium scall Sharepoint 2010 Farm and would like to know how many databases are required and what about the other Database requirements?

I understood that we may need an admin db however what are the other databases are required, especially for the SSA components?

Also do we need another search service application to crawl the people profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation, there is only one administration database required. The actual index is stored in file system so there is no database required.

Note that SharePoint Search 2010 also creates Crawl and Property databases.

List of databases for SharePoint 2010 are documented here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=187969

Comment: Why do we need to create two SSA for Fast for Sharepoint 2010?

What is the use of Content & Query SSA? do we need to do a full crawl for both of the SSA?

Comment: I have not configured FAST myself but sounds like these are topology related questions... Usually Technet is the nest place to understand logical architecture of SharePoint and related products. Just in case you have not already seen this helpful link to understand FAST Search topology: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599528.aspx